# How to print hash of anonymous hashes?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

How would I get value of stones if hash structure is as follows?

```
%HoA = 
(
[stones    => "ruby"],
[metal     => "gold"],
);
```

I am trying to get using `print $HoA->{stones};`, but no value is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the members of `%HoA` are arrays, not hashes. In fact, what you have is a hash with one element.  The key of that element is a reference to an array holding two elements: "stones" and "ruby".  The value of that element is a reference to an array holding two elements: "metal" and "gold".

I'm guessing you want a hash that will contain a list of stones, a list of metals etc.  The way to do that is:

```
%HoA = 
(
    stones    => ["ruby"],
    metal     => ["gold"],
);
```

Now $HoA{stones} is a reference to an array containing the single element "ruby".

```
print @($HoA{stones});
```

should give you:

```
ruby
```